# SyntaxError sem erros aparentes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

entrada = input("DLL Nome: ")
saida = entrada+"_output.txt"

file = bytearray(open(entrada, 'rb').read())

with open(saida, 'w') as output:

    for count, byte in enumerate(file, 1):

        output.write(f'{byte:#0{4}x},' + ('\n' if not count % 16 else ' '))
```

Meu erro é:

```
output.write(f'{byte:#0{4}x},' + ('\n' if not count % 16 else ' '))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT1: Estou usando Python 3.7

Comment: Para se ver , está ok mesmo - há uma chance de você ter digitado um caractére não imprimível,  de controle, aí no meio - isso causa um erro de sintaxe sem causa visível ( se foi isso o tal caractere não veio para cá quando você colou o código - aqui funcionou).
Tente comentar essa  linha (e adicionar um "pass") - se o erro sumir, redigite a linha (copiar e colar vai colar o caractere invisível junto)

Comment: Ao copiar o código para meu ambiente virtual, o mesmo funcionou corretamente, estava dando erro de sintaxe ao tentar executar em python 2, mas ao usar especificamente o python3 ele funciona, certifique-se realmente de que está usando a versão do python3, se estiver executando pelo terminal, execute usando: python3 nome.py

Answer (score -1):

Eu resolvi o problema reinstalando o Python, não sei ao certo o que aconteceu, mas creio que no momento da instalação devo ter selecionado alguma opção de cadeia de caracteres ou algo do gênero. Mas se alguém mais tiver este problema, recomendo desinstalar a versão(ões) do Python e reinstalar, para mim, isso resolveu.